# make android Lock Screen and home screen

Tags: android, homescreen, lockscreen

I want to make android lock screen but dont know how to implement and start.
Please give me some lock screen example(not pattern n password lock) and instruction to make lock screen.
and also give me code to apply own made lock screen as a default lock on android.

and also give me that how to make home screen.

Comment: I suggest you directly doenmload the source from android

Comment: You may check my answer, I think will help you achieve what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/28603790/3300883

Answer (score 2):

The source code for the Android lock screen can be found in the 
 platform/frameworks/policies/base Git repository, in the phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java file.

You can read the instructions [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

You can read the source file [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_policies_base/blob/master/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java)

Comment: ya, i show that but i cant find SlidingTab in eclips while making lock screen and wht to write in AndroidManifest.xml file ?