# Lock Screen App for android >= 4.0.3

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm trying to develop an android app that will replace the stock `lock screen` and acquire the basic functionality of a typical `lock screen`. I'm planning to support the app from `API level 15` and higher. But I'm facing some problem regarding `lock screen` behaviour. I'm not yet able to disable the `home` and `recent button` of `soft navigation bar`. I've found lot of examples in stack, github and other sources but those are not so useful.

I've tried in following way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Added following flags in LockActivity

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

But didn't get any effective solutions. I've found [ZUI Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zuimeia.suite.lockscreen.international) a very nice app doing what I actually want. How they are accessing the permissions 
to work like a default lock screen ?

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to make a guide to let user to disable system lockscreen in Settings(by send a intent), after user block the system screen, your lock screen will work perfectly.

Comment: @SHICONGCAO didn't work in this way. Do you think I need to acquire some permissions (like device admin) to have the functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a lockscreen app too and I'd like to help you too.

You can check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983462/creating-custom-lockscreen-in-android/28603790#28603790) for understanding the concept behind Views and TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR.

But I tweaked the code a bit and here's my version:

```
WindowManager mWindowManager;
RelativeLayout mLscreenlayout;

WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH|
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE| 
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
     mWindowManager = ((WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
     mLscreenlayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
     getWindow().setAttributes(localLayoutParams);


     View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_lockscreen, this.mLscreenlayout);
     this.mWindowManager.addView(mLscreenlayout, localLayoutParams); 

public void onDestroy()
    {
        mWindowManager.removeView(this.mLscreenlayout);
        mLscreenlayout.removeAllViews();

        super.onDestroy();
        //myThread.interrupt();
        Log.i("Daze","Lockscreen Activity Destroyed");
    }
```

Also, there's library on GitHub [here](https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker) to lock the home button. Hope this helps :)